# Build Server Will NOT Deploy certain apps

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

We recently upgraded to TFS2012 and now we have an MVC app and a WCF Service both built in VS2012 that WILL compile and build but will NOT deploy.  Any ideas on what I should research?  I read that MS now only allows deployment of certain types of files and web files are not of that type.  Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Before we started having the issues.  We would use VS2010 set up a build definition then have the build server build it nightly and deploy it to the hosting server.  No issues.  Once we upgraded to TFS2012 the build server will still build the solution but will not deploy it.  There are no errors, it just want deploy.  At first it was just one particular MVC app, but now we are seeing it in another WCF service. So the build definition worked prior to the upgrade.

Comment: the MVC app and the WCF service are both actively in development using VS2012, so I didnt know if it was the fact that they are being developed in VS2012 that was causing it and if so, how to accommodate for that?

Answer (score 0):

The default build processes in a standard on-premises TFS2012 installation do not do any deployment out of the box. Therefore in answer to your question I would personally look at the custom deployment steps that are happening and maybe put some additional logging in to identify the problem.

Often being able to remote desktop into the build server and then perform the steps that your build process would have taken is a good way to check things like this.

As the upgrade process usually involves re-installing the build agent my guess would be that it could be a permissions problem, maybe the build agent was installed as a different user to how it was running in the TFS 2010 configuration and that process/user does not have permissions to deploy the build.  But that is just a guess - digging into the deployment steps that you added to your build process should help you track it down.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The deployment steps in the build definition haven't changed and the userid and password within the build definition works fine deploying other apps on that same server.  So I dont think it is a permissions issue.  We can go to the server directly and deploy the apps, they just will not deploy using the build server.